# How can I convert normal javascript code to jQuery

Tags: jquery

People are recommending me that I should convert this code to jquery, but how and where, are there any tools or how do you do that and why XMLHttpRequest is not good with jQuery??

I have this code:

```
function showVal(str) {
  if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "* Please type in School Name.";
    return;
  }

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
      if (xmlhttp.status == 200) { // break this into 2 statements so you can handle HTTP errors
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
      } else {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "AJAX Error (HTTP "+xmlhttp.status+")";
      }
    }
  }; // functions declared in this way should be followed by a semi colon, since the function declaration is actually a statement.

  // encodeURIComponent() does all the escaping work for you - it is roughly analogous to PHP's urlencode()

  // xmlhttp.open("GET","ajaxFuncs2.php?q="+encodeURIComponent(str),true);
  xmlhttp.open("GET","ajaxFuncs2.php?q="+encodeURIComponent(str),true);

  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: You should begin by read some documentation about jQuery. Begin with the official website http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works

Comment: If it works, there may not be any reason to switch.  In fact, if you are not using (and loading) jQuery now, then converting to jQuery just adds to the size of the page.

Comment: It doesn't work with my other jquery code :S

Comment: @Kees: Does the OP really deserve +8 rep because he got downvoted?

Comment: @JustinSatyr well... if nobody explains the down vote, then that is the consequence. You can't spank someone without explaining why IMO. (Rep is +3)

Answer (score 2):

If you really wanted to, conversion would make your code much more compact...but with the added penalty of having a dependency on jQuery. Personally, if you're comfortable handling the cross browser issues for this relatively simple piece of functionality I see no reason to convert it.

That being said, it'd be relatively easy to convert:

```
function showVal(str){
    if(str == ''){
        $('#txtHint').html("* Please type in School Name.");
        return;
    }

    $.get({
        url: 'ajaxFuncs2.php?q='+encodeURIComponent(str),
        success: function(data){ $('#txtHint').html(data); },
        error: function(){ $('#txtHint').html('AJAX Error'); }
    });
}
```

...or thereabouts

Comment: @Drazek - It should at least be enough to get you started in the right direction. It's impossible for me to write your code for you without knowing any requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite it using [jQuery's AJAX engine](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/). It should be an easy task.

But you have to ask yourself the age old question: *should I fix what ain't broken?*

Using `$.ajax` it would look like this:

```
function showVal(str){ 
    if(str == null || str == ''){ 
        $('#txtHint').html('* Please type in School Name.');
    }
    else {
        $.ajax({ 
                url: 'ajaxFuncs2.php?q='+encodeURIComponent(str), 
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){ $('#txtHint').html(data); },
                error: function(request, status, error){ $('#txtHint').html('AJAX Error (HTTP ' + status + ')'); } 
            }); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Using jQuery could make life a little bit easier, because you see what the code does instead of all the browser specifics.

Comment: it doesn't work, and how it can be easy task, when I have no javascript knowledge

Comment: @Drazek well... you'll need some basic JavaScript knowledgde to program JavaScript. But there are many resources on that (like http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp). Just read up a bit.